# Como ver minhas respostas que tiveram mais visualizações?

Tags: suporte, data-explorer

Se faço a seguinte pesquisa

> [image: user:201 views:50]

Só recebo resultado das *Perguntas* que fiz, mas queria saber das *Respostas*...

É possível saber quais respostas minhas tiveram mais *views*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, mas é preciso usar o **Data Explorer**.
Achei uma query no Meta post [*Get total number of views for my contribution*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252734/1287812):

> http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/187290/get-viewcount-on-posts-user-contributed-to
>
> ```sql
> SELECT DISTINCT(p2.id) as [Post Link], p2.ViewCount 
> FROM Posts as p1
> JOIN Posts p2 ON p1.ParentId = p2.Id
> WHERE p1.OwnerUserId = ##UserId## or p2.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
> ```

É preciso do *User ID* no site em questão, e selecionar o site desejado:
<sub>(aparentemente, o favicon do SOPT tá bugado lá no DE)</sub>
[image]